# Negative values in r.watershed flow accumulation

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, hydrology

I am trying to process a DTM by using r.watershed in QGIS 2.14.3, with the GRASS GIS toolbox. It should be the file named: "Number of cells that drain through each cell".

I get some negative values, even if the shape of drainage line seems very correct. I think that the problem might be the number format (like float or integer).

I am working on a .tiff dem, but it was extracted by clipping from a .asc bigger dem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: if you look at [the help](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.watershed.html) it looks like flow accumulations can be negative. have you tried the -a option ('use positive flow accumulation even for likely underestimates')?

Comment: Ok, thanks!, this has solved the problem! But I think this also means that my dem is too small for covering the whole basin, is it right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Flow accumulation is negative when some of the flow comes from outside the current region. The neg value is just a reminder that the real flow accum would be larger if you had a larger DEM. But your basin could still be fully covered. The cells with neg flow accumulation could be small sub-basins at the edges, outside your basin of interest.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I completed the flow acc elaboration. Seems that r.watershed is a very powerful tool, but I needed to control it better. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

It was solved long ago in the comments, but better as an answer.

Quoting the manual of r.watershed:

> Negative numbers indicate that those cells possibly have surface runoff from outside of the current geographic region. Thus, any cells with negative values cannot have their surface runoff [..] calculated accurately.